# Can I extract portion of a binary file without file.read()-ing it?

Tags: python-3.6

I am extracting ascii header from binary files. It doesn't seem to be a fixed size so I cannot rely on exact byte offset to extract this header. From what I could gather, the header starts at the first occurrence of `\x0a\x23` and ends at the first `\x00\x00` after that. So I am simply reading each file and applying a regex to extract what I want.

Is there a faster way to do this without actually reading the file ? (right now, the only improvement I see is to limit the reading to a fixed size that would be large enough to ensure I get the header but not reading the whole file but that doesn't seem like a huge improvement)

**Note:** I will read tens (hundreds even maybe) of thousands of files so any micro-optimization is welcome to make the code as fast as possible.

Here's my code:

```
import re

# Header starts at the first \x0a\x23 occurrence and ends at the first following \x00\x00
HEADER_RE = re.compile(b'(\x0a\x23.+?)\x00\x00', re.DOTALL)

def get_header(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        data = file.read() #TODO: read only the first x bytes: file.read(x)
    try:
        header = HEADER_RE.search(data).group(0)
    except AttributeError:
        header = b''
    return header
```

Comment: Huh?  "extract a portion" implies having to read the file, no?

Comment: My question maybe stupid, I am just wondering if there is a faster way to do what I need. I was hoping there would be ways to locate binary patterns that didn't require to do `file.read()` (but obviously still read the file somehow)